# Componente Jquery de edição de texto

Tags: jquery, editor-de-texto

Estou precisando de usar um editor *Jquery* que chegue mais próximo do *Word.*

- Qual devo usar?
- Alguém tem alguma indicação?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O TinyMCE é um dos mais famosos:

http://www.tinymce.com/

O mais completo creio que seja o CKEditor:

http://ckeditor.com/

Tem também o Aloha, mas esse eu nunca usei:

http://aloha-editor.org/

Comment: @Marconi Qual deles você usa? Você pode editar sua pergunta comentando cada componente, pra que eu possa melhorar minha resposta?

Comment: @Marconi Abra outra pergunta e exponha seu código que poderemos ajudá-lo.

Answer (score 1):

Voce pode utilizar o [Summernote](http://summernote.org/).

Caracteristicas:

- Suporte ao bootstrap 3.x.x
- Leve apenas 80kb  tudo (js e css)
- Interação inteligente com o usuário

### Suporte nos navegadores:

- Safari
- Chrome
- Firefox
- Opera
- Internet Explorer 9+

### Exemplo:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#summernote').summernote();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/summernote/0.7.3/summernote.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/summernote/0.7.3/summernote.js"></script>


<div id="summernote">Hello Summernote</div>
```

[Mais Exemplos [Summernote]](http://summernote.org/examples/)

Comment: Achei bem legal o componente também .